# Taylor expansion vs expansion in physics

Tags: calculus

In physics I often see expansions of the form  $\phi(x+a)=\phi(x)+a\phi'(x)$ for small a. 
How does this coincide with the usual Taylor expansion $\phi(x-a)=\phi(a)+\phi'(a)(x-a) +...$ ?

Comment: You should change the two expressions so that the role of $x$ in the to expressions is the same, and the same for $a$. In the first expression's right-hand side, you're evaluating $\phi$ at $x$ and using small $a$, while in the second expression the roles are swapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative $f'(x)$ of a function $f(x)$ can be defined as
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
Thus for small $h$,
$$f'(x)\approx  \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
Or,
$$f(x+h)\approx f(x)+hf'(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

The first is an expansion around $x$, with a small, and it is a not rigorous way to write

$\phi(x+a)\approx \phi(x)+a\phi'(x)$

or

$\phi(x+a)\sim \phi(x)+a\phi'(x)$

the second is the Taylor’s expansion around x=a.

Answer (score 0):

The first is an expansion around $x = 0$, for small $a$ whilst the second one is around $x = a$.